# Problems with Django logout

Tags: django, python-3.x

I was following a tutorial, but the logout is not working, I have something like this. (Python 3.7)

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
# Auth
url(r'^logout/', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

I get this error (doesn't run):

```
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'logout'
```

I also checked that there is a function called `auth_logout()` on that same path, but it needs a `request` to work, and I have no idea how to do that. It runs without the parameter and when I call the url it does logout, but I get an exception:

```
The view django.contrib.auth.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import logout

    url(r'^logout/', logout, name='logout'),
```

or you can try:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

    url(r'^logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```

Comment: The second one worked nicely, I'm now tinkering with the parameters to get what I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Views module doesn't have logout function. Below code should work.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: This worked nicely, I'm now tinkering with the parameters to get what I wanted, thanks.