# ValueError at /logout/ in Django

Tags: django-forms, django-views

**Views.py**

```
def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('login')
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('login/',views.Login,name='login'),
 path('logout/',views.logout,name='logout'),
```

**Html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<li class="nav-item">
   <a  class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>         </li>
```

**The view django.contrib.auth.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

Exception Location: C:\Users\dheeraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 124

**I also tried it using render and change url format ,but unable to understand where i am doing mistake.**

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51826925/7887883

Comment: Thankyou , i understand where i do mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.
just small changes in url.py

```
path(r'^logout/',views.logout,name='logout'),
```